# Spring Boot 2.5 and Spring Data: @NoRepositoryBean unexpected behaviour in multi-module project

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm facing the following issue in a legacy code that I can't change. I have a multi module project which defines in the commons module a Spring Data interface as below:

```
package commons;
...
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MyCustomRepository<P, I extends Number> extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer>
{
  MyEntity getOneAndCheck();
}
```

In another module I extend this interface as follows:

```
package data;
...
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends MyCustomRepository<MyEntity, Integer>
{
  ...
}
```

So, the idea is that I don't want that Spring Data generates any implementation for the MyEntity getOneAndCheck() method 'cause it is implemented like this:

```
package data;
...
public class MyCustomRepositoryImpl implements MyCustomRepository
{
  ...
  @Override
  public MyEntity getOneAndCheck()
  {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

However, when I'm starting the application, I get the following exception:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract MyEntity commons.MyCustomRepository.getOneAndCheck()! No property getOne found for type MyEntity!
...
```

So what it seems to happen is that Spring Data tries to generate a Query for the MyEntity getOneAndCheck() method, despite the @NoRepositoryBean annotation. This works as expected in the application I'm gonna migrate from Spring 3 with Spring Data to Spring Boot 2.5.

Not sure if the described behavior has anything to do with the fact that there are multiple Maven modules and that the repositories, the entities and the DTOs are in different modules. Not sure neither if there should be any difference between the way it runs currently with Spring and the one with Spring Boot. But the result is that all of the dozens of repositories in this legacy application are failing with the mentioned exception.

It might be important to mention that the main class needs to use annotations in order to tune the scanning:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "...")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"...", "..."})
@EntityScan(basePackages= {"...", "..."})
public class MyApp
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
  }
}
```

Not sure whether these annotations are supposed to change anything from the point of view of @NoRepositoryBean but the issue appeared as soon as I added this Spring Boot main class. It worked okay previously without Spring Boot.

Any suggestion please ?

Many thanks in advance.

Kind regards,

Seymour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things that play together:

1. Spring Data's default custom implementation
2. Repository fragments

None of these apply because:

1. The default custom implementation follows the name of the actual repository.  In your case, the implementation is named `MyCustomRepositoryImpl` whereas the repository name is `MyRepository`. Renaming the implementation to `MyRepositoryImpl` would address the issue
2. Since Spring Data 2.0, the repository detection considers interfaces defined at the repository level as fragment candidates where each interface can contribute a fragment implementation. While the implementation name follows the fragment interface name (`MyCustomRepository` -> `MyCustomRepositoryImpl`), only interfaces without `@NoRepositoryBean` are considered.

You have three options:

- extracting your custom method into its own fragment interface and providing an implementation class that follows the fragment name:

```java
interface MyCustomFragement {
  MyEntity getOneAndCheck();
}

class MyCustomFragementImpl implements MyCustomFragement {
  public MyEntity getOneAndCheck() {…}
}

public interface MyRepository extends MyCustomRepository<MyEntity, Integer>, MyCustomFragment {…}
```

- Set the `repositoryBaseClass` via `@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = …)` to a class that implements the custom method.
- If you cannot change the existing code, you could implement a `BeanPostProcessor` to inspect and update the bean definition for the `JpaRepositoryFactoryBean` by updating `repositoryFragments` and adding the implementation yourself. This path is rather complex and requires the use of reflection since bean factory internals aren't exposed.

Comment: Thanks for these explanations. Not sure of having understood everything but I'll investigate further, given the options above. Just a note to say that the naming issue (MyRepository instead of MyRepositoryImpl) is just a typo.